# Powershell to Audit Folder Permissions Showing Group Membership

Tags: windows, powershell

Background: I've been using Netwrix to audit permissions to network shares for a few years now and It's only ever worked smoothly 1 time..... So I've decided to move on to just an automated powershell script. I've run into a block. When I try to parse out the group members, it doesn't like the network name in front of the group name (TBANK). Then I also need to take the next step of just showing the name instead of the whole output of get-adgroupmember. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm very to to scripting with powershell. Current script below:

```
$OutFile = "C:\users\user1\Desktop\test.csv" # Insert folder path where you want to save your file and its name
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference, Members,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
$FileExist = Test-Path $OutFile 
If ($FileExist -eq $True) {Del $OutFile} 
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 
$Folder = "\\server1.tbank.com\share1"
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
        $ID = $ACL.IdentityReference
        $ID = $ID -replace 'TBANK\' , ''
        $ACType = $ACL.AccessControlType
        $ACInher = $ACL.IsInherited
        $ACInherFlags = $ACL.InheritanceFlags
        $ACProp = $ACL.PropagationFlags
        $Members = get-adgroupmember $ID.
        $OutInfo = $Folder + "," + $ID  + "," + $Members  + "," + $ACType + "," + $ACInher + "," + $ACInherFlags + "," + $ACProp
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is a way better way to output a CSV file than by trying to write each row yourself (with the risk of missing out required quotes), called `Export-Csv`.

To use that cmdlet, you wil need to create an array of **objects** which is not hard to do.

```
$OutFile = "C:\users\user1\Desktop\test.csv"   # Insert folder path where you want to save your file and its name
$Folder  = "\\server1.tbank.com\share1"

# get the Acl.Access for the folder, loop through and collect PSObjects in variable $result
$result = (Get-Acl -Path $Folder).Access | ForEach-Object {
    # -replace uses regex, so you need to anchor to the beginning of 
    # the string with '^' and escape the backslash by doubling it
    $id = $_.IdentityReference -replace '^TBANK\\'   # remove the starting string "TBANK\"

    # Get-ADGroupMember can return users, groups, and computers. If you only want users, do this:
    # $members = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $id | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user'}).name -join ', '
    $members = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $id).name -join ', '
    # output an onbject with all properties you need
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Folder Path'       = $Folder
        'IdentityReference' = $id
        'Members'           = $members
        'AccessControlType' = $_.AccessControlType
        'IsInherited'       = $_.IsInherited
        'InheritanceFlags'  = $_.InheritanceFlags -join ', '
        'PropagationFlags'  = $_.PropagationFlags -join ', '
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-List

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path $OutFile -Force -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

I've added a lot of inline comments to hopefully make things clear for you.
The `-UseCulture` switch in the Export-Csv line makes sure the field delimiter that is used matches what is set in your system as list separator. This helps when opening the csv file in Excel.

<sup>P.S> the `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet also has a switch called `-Recursive`. With that, it will also get the members from groups inside groups</sup>

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for